# Make a seek bar for media player. 

Tags: java, swing, jmf

I am making a media player using JMF, I want to use my own control components
Can anyone please help me in making a seek bar for media player so that it can play song according to the slider position.

Just suggest me some logic, I can figure out the coding part afterwards

```
if(player!=null){
    long durationNanoseconds = 
    (player.getDuration().getNanoseconds());
    durationbar.setMaximum((int) player.getDuration().getSeconds());
    int duration=(int) player.getDuration().getSeconds();
    int percent = durationbar.getValue();
    long t = (durationNanoseconds / duration) * percent;
    Time newTime = new Time(t);
    player.stop();
    player.setMediaTime(newTime);
    player.start();
    mousedrag=true;
```

Here is the code. Now how can I make the slider move along with the song?
Slider works when I drag/click on it, but it doesn't move with the song.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: When a new song is selected, use a background thread that finds the time of the player and updates the seek bar every second. You can use a JSlider as suggested or create your own component. Assuming that you want the seek bar to move while the song is playing of course...

Comment: Can you please help me with the thread.I am not able to figure out,how shall i start?
with the thread it is
slider.setmaximum=player.getDuration();
slider.setminimum=0;
and the value
and how do i make the seek bar move along with the song.how shall i repaint the frame? @Rempelos

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem with using a slider for this is that when the slider position is moved programmatically, it fires events.  When an event is fired on a slider, it typically means the app. has to do something, such as move the song position.  The effect is a never ending loop.  There is probably a way around this by setting flags and ignoring some events, but I decided to go a different way.

Instead I used a `JProgressBar` to indicate the location in the track, and a `MouseListener` to detect when the user clicks on a separate position.  Update the progress bar use a Swing `Timer` that checks the track location every 50-200 milliseconds.  When a `MouseEvent` is detected, reposition the track.

The bar can be seen in the upper right of this GUI.  Hovering over it will produce a tool tip showing the time in the track at that mouse position.

[image: Duke Box using progress bar for track postion]

Comment: ahh...i like the UI (given that its Swing)

Comment: @SurajChandran Yes, Swing can produce some nice GUIs when used properly.  :)

Comment: @AndrewThompson can you please help me with the code to forward songs with the progress bar.I mean how to start with it,cant figure out.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a JSlider.

You can learn more from the [Slider tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/slider.html)

[image: Slider tutorial]

Comment: In addition this [simple example](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/mkarg/archive/2010/01/03/did-you-know-swingworker-can-send-progress-status) could help (updating the slider via `SwingWorker`)

Comment: ya currently m using a JSlider,but the problem is,for the interface of my media player,i need to give the slider a minimum n maximum value first...
but m thinking slider.maximum=duration of the song
and i can get duration of the song only after it has some mp3 file loaded..if some how i can revalidate the frame...is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to `revalidate` the container in order to change the slider.

Use these lines each time a new player is created:

```
  slider.setMinimum(0);
  slider.setMaximum(duration);
  slider.setValue(0);

  new UpdateWorker(duration).execute();
```

where `duration` is the variable holding the duration of the song in seconds.

And here is the code (used as inner class) which updates the slider:

```
private class UpdateWorker extends SwingWorker<Void, Integer> {

    private int duration;

    public UpdateWorker(int duration) {
        this.duration = duration;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
        for (int i = 1; i <= duration; i++) {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            publish(i);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void process(List<Integer> chunks) {
        slider.setValue(chunks.get(0));
    }

}
```

Now the slider will move to the right until the end of the song.

Also note that unless you want to use a custom slider, JMF provides a simple (and working) slider via `player.getVisualComponent()` (see [this example](http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/javax.swing/make-your-own-java-media-player-to-play-media.html)).

**UPDATE**

In order to pause/resume the worker thread (and thus the slider and the song), here is an example with a button that sets the appropriate flags.

```
private boolean isPaused = false;
JButton pause = new JButton("Pause");
pause.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JButton source = (JButton)e.getSource();
        if (!isPaused) {
            isPaused = true;
            source.setText("Resume");
        } else {
            isPaused = false;
            source.setText("Pause");
        }
    }
});
```

The method `doInBackground` should be changed to something like that:

```
@Override
protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
    for (int i = 0; i <= duration; i++) {
        if (!isPaused) {
            publish(i);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch(InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        while (isPaused) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(50);
                continue;
            } catch(InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Modify it accordingly to pause/resume the song along with the slider.

You should also consider @AndrewThompson's answer.

Comment: I tried your code,it worked,but with some flaws
1st. whenever m associating a 2nd thread with my media player,it hangs for a second (dont know if my low pc config is the issue)
2nd. The slider keep on going even after i pause or stop.

I tried this by myself.i started a newthread and updated the position of the slider with thread.sleep(1000)
the problem is that the player hangs.
**NOTE**: I have associated 1st thread with a progress bar (which also shows the update),hence the slider thread is my 2nd
@Rempelos
it is only lagging,otherwise evrything is fine now.
help me sort out this hang issue

Comment: Thank you .I will try do this the way @AndrewThompson said,because using a seperate thread to move the slider is making the application (PC) hang,until i close it somehow.So currently I am thinking of changing the song's position using the progress bar.

Comment: If it hangs you're not doing it right. Anyway the progressbar is a good alternative