# Get value on clicking jprogressbar

Tags: java, mouseevent, jprogressbar

I am trying to make a player in java.

Have made a seekbar using jprogressbar as shown in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12786346/make-a-seek-bar-for-media-player) in Andrew Thompson's answer,

I have been able to add a mouselistener and detect click on jprogressbar, but how do I get the selected value of jprogressbar to which I will seek my bar to?

I tried,

```
progressBar.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {            
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
           int v = progressBar.getSelectedValue();
       jlabel.setText("----"+v);
      }                                     
});
```

But didn't work as I expected, could not even find anything on internet.

Please help me. Thanks for your time and effort, really appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would probably have to calculate the location on the JProgressBar based solely on the mouse click co-ordinates. You could essential do this:

```
progressBar.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {            
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
       int v = progressBar.getValue();
       jlabel.setText("----"+v);

       //Retrieves the mouse position relative to the component origin.
       int mouseX = e.getX();

       //Computes how far along the mouse is relative to the component width then multiply it by the progress bar's maximum value.
       int progressBarVal = (int)Math.round(((double)mouseX / (double)progressBar.getWidth()) * progressBar.getMaximum());

       progressBar.setValue(progressBarVal);
  }                                     
});
```

Comment: sorry for delay.. let me try this.